# How to replace JButton in JPanel with another JButton

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I am trying the following piece of code in java, but it doesn't seem to work for some strange kind of fashion:

```
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Test Frame");
myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout());

JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
myPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
myFrame.add(myPanel);

JButton firstButton = new JButton();
myPanel.add(firstButton);

JButton secondButton = new JButton();
myPanel.remove(firstButton);
myPanel.add(secondButton);
myFrame.repaint();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you expect that will happen ? You do not add `myPanel` to `myFrame`, and if you call `add`, `remove`, `add` on the EDT in the same runnable you will never see the first button added

Comment: Sorry for that, I missed that, while I was typing the above code. Consider it already there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't repaint for `JFrame` (`myFrame.repaint();`), you have to `(re)validate` and `repaint` the nearest container as `JPanel` is in your case

```
JButton secondButton = new JButton();
myPanel.remove(firstButton);
myPanel.add(secondButton);
myPanel.revalidate();
myPanel.repaint();
```

Comment: `revalidate()/repaint()` on the said `JPanel` on which change happened is the key :-) +1 for this

Comment: Thanx for your answer. Seems like revalidate() and then repaint() was all I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `getComponents()` in order to find the the `JButton` index, and `addComponent(Component component, int index)` to add the old one in place, afterwards you could remove the one you want to replace.